# Uninitialized string offset: 0 - Laravel auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to check the session with:

```
<?php

namespace AndyJessop\Socialist\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Auth\Guard;
use AndyJessop\Socialist\AuthenticateUser;

class AuthController extends Controller {

    public $auth;

    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
       $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function login($provider, AuthenticateUser $authenticateUser, Request $request)
    {
        $user = $authenticateUser->execute($request->has('code'), $provider);

        return $user;
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->auth->logout();

        return response()->json(['You have been logged out']);
    }

    public function checkSession()
    {
        $session = $this->auth->check();
        return $session;
    }
}
```

But I get the error: `Uninitialized string offset: 0`

What can be the cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Check your database table and see your record. I think you don't have some record in it.